# Which would be faster out of compact vs reduce to remove nil elements from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say you have an array in ruby and you want to remove all the nil elements, typically you would use `compact`, but could having a reducer that looks like `.reduce([]) { |x, i| x<<i unless i.nil?; x }` do the same thing faster?

Comment: I suppose you could do benchmarks but I'd be flabbergasted if [Array#compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-compact)--being written in C and purpose-built--did not leave `reduce` in the dust.

Comment: Creating an array by adding elements one after another generally isn't very fast as it needs to be resized continuously. It's better to copy / duplicate the existing array and then remove the `nil` elements. Which is exactly what `compact` does.